# Android Gradle separate variables

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have a large gradle file and now I want to have a separate gradle file that contains only constants. As I understood I just had to create a constants.gradle file and use:

```
apply from: 'constants.gradle'
```

in my main build.gradle file

My constants.gradle file contains:

```
def MY_VARIABLE = 1
```

If I want to reference that variable in build.gradle i get the following error:

```
"Could not find property ..."
```

EDIT: I want to use this variable as a buildConfigField in each product flavor

Comment: You can define separate constant file in your project and in that file you can define all of your constants. No need to define in build.gradle

Comment: I am aware of that, but as I stated in my question I get an error "Could not find property ..."

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Do you mean a separate file such as constants.properties instead of constants.gradle?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found something that answers my question. I'm attaching a link to this nice article: http://saulmm.github.io/squeezing-gradle-builds/

I was trying to solve the problem in a different way that this article does.